# Google Apps Script success handler receives 'null' from server function even though it has a value server side

Tags: google-apps-script

I am making a small web app with GAS to search data from a google spreadsheet. On my front end I have a form to make a search and display the data.
When I click on the search button of this form, I have this script that fires:

```
  document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("click", searchSheet);
  
  function searchSheet() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(generateTable).getFullData();
  }
```

the function getFullData() in the file Code.gs retrieves the data I want to work with in my spreadsheet and transform it in an array of objects.

```
function getFullData() {
  const rawData = ws.getRange(2, 2, ws.getLastRow()-1, ws.getLastColumn()-1).getValues();
  const headers = ["region", "country", "location", "clientType", "clientName", "projectTitle", "status", "startDate", "endDate", "workType", "contact", "fundingOrigin", "partners", "currency", "projectValue", "staffProvided", "internalStaff", "gdLink", "sampleSize", "blurb", "themes", "finalReport", "fieldworkBudget", "projectCode"];
  const data = rawData.map((r,i) => {
    let obj = {};
    obj.id = i;
    r.forEach((e,j) => obj[headers[j]] = e);
    return obj
  });
  console.log(data);
  return data;  
}
```

After this the success handler fires the function generateTable

```
  function generateTable(rawData) {
    console.log(rawData);
    //... rest of the function to search the array and create a nice table to display the data.
```

However console.log(rawData); returns 'null' and when I check the logs server side I have the array of objects I want.
I already used something similar on another project so I am a bit perplex as why the succes handler receives the null value.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: A server function can only return certain types of values. From the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values: "Legal parameters and return values are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, as well as JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects and arrays." I had a date type in my array of object therefore the return value was null.